# Passing a collection to multiple views

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js, pagination, backbone-views

I'm trying to pass a paginated collection (`backbone.paginator` plugin) to multiple views so it's shared and I can call functions of my three views using the same collection.

However, my main view (`AttendeesView`) which is calling other views (`PaginationBarView` and `AttendeeView` per pages).
I tryed to pass it by the constructor of my views, by the router.
I can't seem to make it work so I'd need an idea so I could work on it.

**EDIT :** By the way, the error I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined` on my PaginatedBar when I try to add an event to my collection. It's not found.

`AttendeesCollection` (Paginated)

```
define([
    'jQuery',
    'Underscore',
    'Backbone',
    'models/AttendeeModel',
    'libs/plugins/backbone.paginator'
],function($, _, Backbone, Attendee,Paginator){
    var AttendeesCollection = Paginator.requestPager.extend({
        model: Attendee,
        ... (Works)
    return AttendeesCollection;
});
```

---

```
define([
    'jQuery',
    'Underscore',
    'Backbone',
    'libs/plugins/bootstrap-dropdown',
    'text!templates/PaginationBar.phtml'
],function($, _, Backbone, twdd, PaginationBarTPL){
    var PaginationBar = Backbone.View.extend({
        events: {
            'click a.PBNext': 'nextResultPage',
            'click a.PBPrev': 'previousResultPage',
            'click a.PBSort': 'updateSortBy',
            'click a.PBPage': 'gotoPage'
        },
        initialize: function(){
            _.bindAll(this,'render','updateSortBy','nextResultPage', 'previousResultPage', 'gotoPage');
            this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
            this.collection.on('change', this.render, this);
        }
            (...)
    });
    return PaginationBar;
});
```

---

```
define([
    'jQuery',
    'Underscore',
    'Backbone',
    'facade',
    'views/PaginationBarView',
    'text!templates/attendees.phtml',
    'collections/AttendeesCollection'
],function($, _, Backbone,facade,PaginationBarView,AttendeesTPL,AttendeesCollection){
    var AttendeesView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: "#attendees",
        collection: new AttendeesCollection,
        paginationbar: new PaginationBarView({collection: this.collection}),

        initialize: function(){

            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'onClose');

            $(this.el).find(".paginationBar").append(this.paginationbar.render().el)
            this.collection.on('change', this.addAll, this);
            this.collection.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
            this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
            this.collection.pager();
        },
              (...)
    });
    return AttendeesView;
});
```

Comment: We would appreciate if you would make the effort to not just copy/paste your application code but re-create the issue in the most minimal code example.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't much time left to ask my question before leaving work. But you could've edited it if it really bothered you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the `PagniationBarView` in the view definition, before `this.collection` exists. I'd suggest moving it into `initialize()`:

```
var AttendeesView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: "#attendees",
    collection: new AttendeesCollection,
    paginationbar: null, // Do not create the view here

    initialize: function(){

        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'onClose');

        // Create the view here now that this.collection exists
        this.paginationbar = new PaginationBarView({collection: this.collection});

        // ...

    }
});
return AttendeesView;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem and a colleague just figured it out before I saw your message.
Now I know I won't initialize any var depending on others out of my initialize...